# Remove invisiable bearer by div that has radius

Tags: css, html, web

**My problem**

Im trying to to have content fit next to an div that has: css-    `Border-radius:100%;`

[I want the text to be by the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCded.png)

> Why is there a gab between the text and image?

[Notice how even tho the div has the radius, its still, **square**; Its invisible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfyhS.png)

> If there a way to make the "invisible bearer radius" too?

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jARN.png)

> I am doing that(above) by using `position:absolute; right:integer;`

** I do not want to make the next to the radius div by using **`position: absolute;`**

I feel like this is not professional.

**My Question**

How do i make the text on the right, right next to the image **without** using Position: absolute;

**Code-html5**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Xlaeo-Hom</title>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>Xlaeo-Hom</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\defaultCSS-css.css\default-css.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=".\center-css.css" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <div>

            <div class="vvn_flex vvn_flex_center">
                <div class="vvn_main_wrapper">
                    <main role="main">

                        <section>

                            <span class="vvn_flex vvn_connect_wrp">

<section class="vvn_flex vvn_prjwrooadf">
  <span class="">
    <div class="vvn_prj_medContoon vvn_relPos">
      <div class="vvn_project_media_holder vvn_mediaProject_border">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/27/10/30/robot-2791671_960_720.jpg"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </span>
                            <span class="">
<div class="vvn_project_abnJI322323" >
  < want to be next to the image :(
</div>
</span>
                        </section>

                        </span>

                        </Section>


                    </main>
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>



    </body>

    </html>
</head>

<body>

    <div>

        <div class="vvn_flex vvn_flex_center">
            <div class="vvn_main_wrapper">
                <main role="main">

                    <section>
                        <!-- media holder_slide_image-->

                    </Section>


                </main>
            </div>
        </div>



    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

**Code-css**

```
 body{
     color:gray;
     margin: 0;
     padding:0;
}
 li{
     list-style-type: none;
}
 .vvn_theme_main{
     margin-top:1rem;
}
 .vvn_flex{
     display: flex;
}
 .vvn_flex_center{
     justify-content: center;
}
 .vvn_flex_dec{
     flex-direction: column;
}
 .vvn_main_wrapper{
     width:90%;
}
 .vvn_1flex{
     flex:1;
}
 .vvn_theme_border{
     border:1px solid lightgray;
}
 .vvn_brgborder{
     border-top:1px solid lightgray;
     border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}
 img{
     width:100%;
     height: 100%;
}
 .vvn_theme_padding{
     padding-left:1rem;
     padding-right: 1rem;
}
 .vvn_theme_margintb{
     padding-top:1rem;
     padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
 .vvn_relPos{
     position: relative;
}
 .vvn_auto_left{
     margin-left:auto;
}
 .vvn_auto_right{
     margin-right: auto;
}
 .vvn_connect_wrp{
     margin-top: 100px;
}
 .vvn_prjwrooadf{
     flex:1;
}
 .vvn_prj_medContoon{
}
 .vvn_project_media_holder{
     height:480px;
     width:480px;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .vvn_mediaProject_border{
     border-radius: 100%;
     border:1px solid gray;
}
 .vvn_project_abnJI322323{
     line-height: 40px;
}
```

Comment:  I can believe it, my post actually got some upvotes it's usually like -72 downvotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/nx12s6y0/

this works for me, let me know if this is what u wanted

```
 .vvn_project_abnJI322323{
     line-height: 40px;
     margin-left:-120px;  /*add this*/
}
```

Comment: @Wofo this solution is exactly the same as doing position absolute and right, you will always have issue when the text is in more than 1 line

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cannot use classic CSS to achieve something like this. Even if you apply border radius, transformation, etc all the element are treated like rectangulare elements. So you need to use more advanced/complex techniques.

One of these techniques is `shape-outside` (which unfortunately is [not well supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=shape-outside)).

As you can read [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/shape-outside/):

> The shape-outside property controls how content will wrap around a
>   floated element’s bounding-box. Typically this is so that text can
>   reflow over a shape such as a circle, ellipse or a polygon

So this will do exactly what you need and here is an example :

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: auto;
}

.shape {
  float: left;
  shape-outside: circle(50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/200/" class='shape'> Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsume Lorem ipsumeLorem
</div>
```

As you can see it's pretty simple to use. There is also a JS polyfill that allow you to make this working with browser that doesn't support the CSS implementation:

https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/css-shapes-polyfill

---

*Here is the result of the snippet in case you are using a browser that doesn't support `shape-outside`*

[image]

Comment: @Wofo that's why i said it's not well supported :) and i added the link so you can see which browser support this. And also provided the polyfill that can make it work using JS

Comment: Thanks dude I might just do the js way